# Csrf token is missing problem in my flask route

Tags: json, forms, api, flask, response

Csrf token missing problem in my flask route i mention my error please review my code and find solution because i am new to flask

```
My app.py file:


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@csrf.exempt
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            name = request.form['name']
            email = request.form['email']
            gender = request.form['gender']
            username = request.form['username']
            password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(request.form['password']))
            user = User(name=name, email=email, gender=gender, username=username, password=password)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            response = {"succcess":"User registered successfully and now you can login"}
            return jsonify(response)
        elif not form.validate_on_submit():
            response = {"errors":form.errors}
            return jsonify(response)

My error in response:

{
  "errors": {
    "csrf_token": [
      "The CSRF token is missing."
    ]
  }
}

How i solve this issue I am new to flask web framework
```

Csrf token missing problem in my flask route i mention my error please review my code and find solution because i am new to flask

Comment: You need to add {{form.csrf_token}} in the form tag.

Comment: but i want to solve this error in postman